# Receiving Black frames only from embedded camera using openCV and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, camera, frames

I am trying to do a simple camera application in QT using openCV, but i have problem with black frames.

The point is, when i run my application on desktop with USB camera, everything seems to work, i am getting frames, and everything is showing in QGraphicsView.

The problem starts when i run my app in laptop with embedded camera. While my app is running, on QGraphicsView i can see only black frames..

Here is a sample of my code:

First of all that's my custom QGraphicsView:

```
class CustomGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomGraphicsView(QWidget *parent);
    ~CustomGraphicsView();

     void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
     QGraphicsPixmapItem *pItem;
     QGraphicsScene *pScene;
     QThread *p_worker;
     QTimer *p_timer;
     CustomThread *p_MyCustomThread;

public slots:
     void StartThread();
     void GetFrame(QPixmap);

};
```

```
CustomGraphicsView::CustomGraphicsView(QWidget *parent): QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    pScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    setScene(pScene);
    pItem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem();
    pItem->setPixmap(pixmap);
    pScene->addItem(pItem);
}

void CustomGraphicsView::StartThread()
{
    p_worker = new QThread();
    p_MyCustomThread = new CustomThread();
    p_MyCustomThread->moveToThread(p_worker);
    connect(p_worker, SIGNAL(started()), p_MyCustomThread,SLOT(StartCamera()));
    connect(p_MyCustomThread, SIGNAL(SendImage(QPixmap)), this, SLOT(GetFrame(QPixmap)));
    p_worker->start();
}

void CustomGraphicsView::GetFrame(QPixmap pix)
{
    pItem->setPixmap(pix);
    pScene->update();
}
```

And here is my class which receive frames from camera, convert it to QPixmap and send to QGraphicsView with SIGNAL/SLOT.

```
class CustomThread : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomThread();
    VideoCapture cam;
    Mat frame;
    void RunTaking();

public slots:
    void StartCamera();


signals:
    void SendImage(QPixmap);

};

void CustomThread::RunTaking()
{
    while(1)
    {
        cam >> frame;
        cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGB);
        QImage image = QImage((uchar*) frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        QPixmap pix = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
        emit SendImage(pix);
    }
}

void CustomThread::StartCamera()
{
    if(cam.open(0))
    {
        RunTaking();
    }
}
```

I was trying to do same thing with labels, with no custom classes, but nothing was working.

Maybe i am doing something wrong? If someone know the solution, i will be grateful for tips.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: can you try to deep copy the QImage or the Pixmap before emitting? Can you try to omit the while-loop (replace it by sending a "finishedCapture" signal and connect it to the "RunTaking" slot.

Comment: Of course i was trying to make deep copy. The problem is somewhere else.. I think when i'my trying to get frame from camera with openCV in ANOTHER thread, it doesn't work. How did i find out it? For example function cvtColor throws assert error. Second thing, when i call "namedWindow()" function it starts working, but it opens also unnecessary window with nohing in it. I do not know why, maybe it is because of old version of openCV?